# Dynamically change dates in cypress fixtures

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

In my Cypress test, I have a field containing a date, and I want it to be dynamic to the test run date.

I tried to handle it this way:

```
export const interceptGetEntity = () => {
  cy.intercept('GET', 'my/api/entities/123145',
    (req) => {
    cy.fixture('get-entity').then((entity: Entity) => {
        const now = new Date();
        const thisMonth = now.getMonth();
        const thisYear = now.getFullYear();
        entity.steps.forEach((step, index) => {
          step.effectiveDate = formatDateString(new Date(thisYear, thisMonth + index, 1));
        })
        req.reply(entity);
      });
    }).as('getEntity');
};
```

But then I get this error:

> Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also
> invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.
>
> The command that returned the promise was:
>
> > cy.wait()
>
> The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:
>
> > cy.fixture()
>
> Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to
> wrap them or return your own promise.
>
> Cypress will resolve your command with whatever the final Cypress
> command yields.
>
> The reason this is an error instead of a warning is because Cypress
> internally queues commands serially whereas Promises execute as soon
> as they are invoked. Attempting to reconcile this would prevent
> Cypress from ever resolving.Learn more

I, obviously, do not want apply this logic to every test but want to make it in 1 common place.
Is there a better way to manipulate my fixture data?

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple synchronous workaround

Instead of:

```
    (req) => {
    cy.fixture('get-entity').then((entity: Entity) => {
        const now = new Date();
        const thisMonth = now.getMonth();
        const thisYear = now.getFullYear();
        entity.steps.forEach((step, index) => {
          step.effectiveDate = formatDateString(new Date(thisYear, thisMonth + index, 1));
        })
        req.reply(entity);
      });
    }
```

I am just fetching the JSON from the file with a simple `require`:

```
    (req) => {
        const entity = require('../../../fixtures/get-entity.json');
        const now = new Date();
        const thisMonth = now.getMonth();
        const thisYear = now.getFullYear();
        entity.steps.forEach((step, index) => {
          step.effectiveDate = formatDateString(new Date(thisYear, thisMonth + index, 1));
        })
        req.reply(entity);
    }
```